# ERDAS file not recognized as ERDAS Hierarchal File Architecture (EFHA)?

Tags: erdas-imagine, accuracy

I am trying to do an accuracy assessment in Erdas using "user defined ground control points" (I collected the GPS points myselfin the field using a handheld GPS).

However, when I load the thematic image I want to validate, I get an error message saying the file is not an EFHA file (ERDAS Hierarchal File Architecture) which results in the file not being loaded into the CellArray.

Any idea on how I can I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't know ERDAS, so can't help you there, but...

You might want to add some tags like Erdas, GPS, etc, to get more responses, and maybe edit your post title. Based on your post, a suggested title might be 'ERDAS file not recognized as EFHA'. Just saying, your post title doesn't say much about what you're looking for.

Comment: What is the format your thematic layer?(.img,.tiff,..etc)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I came across the same thing trying to run an unsupervised classification on a .PNG image. I took a RS in Erdas last year and never ran into this error before now. My main guess is that the image I'm using is not a true geoimage but just a file I got from Google Earth. Secondly, it could have something to do with where the file is stored. No idea, though. No experience with Erdas support but I might try a few more things before that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fix:

1) Import your image and convert it to an .img

If this does not fix the problem then try the following:

2) Click on the "manage data" tab, and click on edit image metadata
3) Change the raster type to "thematic" if it isn't already
4) select "compute pyramids and statistics"

That should sort out the issue.